# Local variable resets when I'm using the debugger C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, reset

I'm using the debugger to check if my programm works but I'm getting a segfault on a precise line. when I'm checking what's wrong, a local variable says `<no such value>`. What's happening? I've checked its value for each k and it's working until k=36. Do you think that local variables are reseted if I'm using it in a too long loop? I remember that I've used it in a loop where k=41 and it was working very well.

Variables of my class:

```
masseVolumique= 7850;
dExterieur= 0.1778;
epaisseur= 0.019;
masseFlotteur1 = 526;
masseFlotteur2 = 94;
largeurFlotteur1 = 1.35+2;
largeurFlotteur2 = 0.83+2;
rayonBends = 0.699;
precision = 2;
```

All the other variables are defined and I can see their value in the debugger mode.

```
int k=0;
j=0;
double theta=0;
double phi=0;
double offsetDebut;
double offsetFin;
double r=0;
int nbPos = 0;
for(int i=0;i<nbSegments;i++)
{
    theta=acos((coordonnees[i+1][0]-coordonnees[i][0])/pow(pow(coordonnees[i+1][0]-coordonnees[i][0],2)+pow(coordonnees[i+1][1]-coordonnees[i][1],2),0.5));

    phi=acos((coordonnees[i+1][2]-coordonnees[i][2])/pow(pow(coordonnees[i+1][0]-coordonnees[i][0],2)+pow(coordonnees[i+1][1]-coordonnees[i][1],2)+pow(coordonnees[i+1][2]-coordonnees[i][2],2),0.5));
    if(i==0)
    {
        offsetDebut=3+largeurFlotteur1/2;
    }
    else
    {
        offsetDebut=rayonBends+largeurFlotteur1/2;
    }

    if(i==(nbSegments-1))
    {
        offsetFin=3+largeurFlotteur1/2;
    }
    else
    {
        offsetFin=rayonBends+largeurFlotteur1/2;
    }
    j=0;

    do
    {
        r=j*precision+offsetDebut; //segfault: precision <no such value>
        tabPos[k*5+0]=k;
        tabPos[k*5+1]=i+1;
        tabPos[k*5+2]=coordonnees[i][0]+r*cos(theta)*sin(phi);
        tabPos[k*5+3]=coordonnees[i][1]+r*sin(theta)*sin(phi);
        if(r*cos(phi)<0.01)
        {
            tabPos[k*5+4]=coordonnees[i][2];
        }
        else
        {
            tabPos[k*5+4]=coordonnees[i][2]+r*cos(phi);
        }
        k=k+1;
        j=j+1;

    }
    while (r<(segments[i]-offsetFin)) ;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There could be some overflow that may indirectly set a wrong value to your `precision` variable. Check your array size, access, etc. We don't have enough information to hep you more.

Comment: `tabPos[k*5+0]=k;` is your tabPos long enough ?

Comment: Show all relevant code in the question

Comment: I think I've found the problem thanks to Thomas. My tabPos isn't long enough. Well, actually it is long enough but there are too much iterations in my loop. I'm having a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem came from the calculation of tabPos length. I was calculating a too short length. In the loop, I was trying to access part of tabPos that were not declared. 
Actually, I think a lot of segfault problem comes from index problems. I'll look at this very carefully now.